# Read the version and other project metadata from project.json

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

In an ASP.NET Core ( ASP 5, ASP vNext):

How can I read the version and other meta data in the *project.json* in my Razor views?

My `project.json` file is something like this:

```
{ 
    "version" : "1.0.0-*",
    "authors" : ["author 1", "author 2"],
    "description" : "my project description"
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You are aware that it's a JSON file and that JSON.NET can deserialize that right?

Comment: @MaximeRouiller-MVP I was wondering if there is a recommended way to access this info. Similar to the way we access to the `appsettings.json` in the _Startup.cs_ e.g.: `Configuration["Data:DefaltConnection:ConnectionString"]`

Comment: Well... https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/1.0.0-rc1-final/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime/Project.cs now whether you can require it through DI or not? Another question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the options model. I have created a sample to read the version number out to the layout page next to the footer [here](https://github.com/edrohler/ASPNETCORE1.0/tree/master/OptionsSample) and you can read about configuration [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html). Lastly, there is a great project for live.asp.net created by Damian Edwards of the ASP.NET team [here](https://github.com/aspnet/live.asp.net). I hope this helps.